# LSD Radix Sort to unequal strings Python

Tags: python, string, radix-sort

I'm not sure how the LCD Radix Sort is performed to strings of unequal length. I referred many sites but I failed to understand the logic behind it to code it in Python. Can someone please explain the logic behind it so that I could code it in Python. Thanks in advance.

Comment: I don't know what sites you looked at. [The first one that came up in a web search](https://www.growingwiththeweb.com/sorting/radix-sort-lsd/) has a pretty nice explanation, sorting numbers by base 10 with different digit lengths, and it includes implementations in multiple languages, including Python. If there's something you don't understand about their explanation, can you try to clarify what it is?

Comment: Well I do understand how to sort numbers, but when sorting strings of unequal length we need to append a character/characters to the end of the string to make it to the required length. I'm not sure whether his is the correct logic.